# Selecting specific element within a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a contact form, and I am having problems with jQuery. I want to select specific input fields that have an error and apply the class `err`. Unfortunately, my code selects all inputs when there is an error. I am having trouble identifying which part of my logic is wrong.

```
$('#send_mail').click(function(){
    $("#contact_body").find('label').each(function(){
        var contact_label = $('input[required=true], textarea[required=true]'); 
        var label_check = $(this).find(contact_label);
        $(contact_label).removeClass('err');
        if (!$.trim($(label_check).val())){
            $(contact_label).addClass('err');
        }
    });
});
```

The order of my HTML goes something like so:

```
#contact_body
<label>
  <input>
</label>
```

Comment: It seems that `contact_label` is defined as *all* required inputs and textareas. It looks like you'd want only the inputs/textareas within the current iteration's `label`, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This selects all `input` and `textarea` elements:

```
var contact_label = $('input[required=true], textarea[required=true]');
```

Instead, you should restrict it to the elements *within* the label:

```
var contact_label = $(this).find('input[required=true], textarea[required=true]');
```

Note that `$(contact_label)` and `contact_label` are equivalent in your code, as well as `$(label_check)` and `label_check`.

Also, you can use the `state` parameter of **[toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** to simplify this:

```
contact_label.removeClass('err');
if (!$.trim(label_check.val())){
  contact_label.addClass('err');
}
```

… to this:

```
contact_label.toggleClass('err', !$.trim(label_check.val()));
```

Here's the updated event:

```
$('#send_mail').click(function(){
  $('#contact_body').find('label').each(function(){
    var contact_label = $(this).find('input[required=true], textarea[required=true]'); 
    var label_check = $(this).find(contact_label);

    contact_label.toggleClass('err', !$.trim(label_check.val()));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your original code would work if you just changed this line:

```
$(contact_label).addClass('err');
```

To this:

```
$(label_check).addClass('err');
```

Because `$(contact_label)` references all the required inputs, whereas `$(label_check)` references only the input being checked.

---

But your code could be simplified, and you make unnecessary calls to `$()`, giving it an argument that is already a JQuery object.

I also do not see that you need to loop through the labels. You could loop through the required inputs instead.

```
$('#send_mail').click(function(){
    $("#contact_body").find(':input[required]').each(function() {
        var $input = $(this);
        $input.removeClass('err');
        if (!$.trim($input.val())){
            $input.addClass('err');
        }
    });
});
```

Which could be shortened by using the `.toggleClass()` function:

```
$('#send_mail').click(function(){
    $("#contact_body").find(':input[required]').each(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('err', !$.trim($input.val()));
    });
});
```

Notes:

- The selector `':input'` matches `<input>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly different approach. Gives a bit more flexibility.

```js
arr = ['first', 'last', 'email', 'msg']; //IDs of fields to check

$('#send_mail').click(function(){
  $('input, textarea').removeClass('err');

  for (var i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++) { //Loop through all field IDs
     if ( $('#'+arr[i]).val() == '' ) {
        $('#'+arr[i]).addClass('err').focus();
        return false;
     }
  }
  //AJAX to send email goes here
  alert('Email sent');
});
```

```css
.err{background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="first">First Name:</label>
<input id="first" type="text" required /><br>
<label for="last">Last Name:</label>
<input id="last" type="text" required/><br>
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input id="email" type="email" required /><br>
<label for="msg">Message:</label>
<textarea id="msg" required></textarea>

<button id="send_mail">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simplify the code, there will be less mistakes:

```
$('#send_mail').click(function(){
    $("#contact_body").find('label').each(function(){
        var field = $(this).find('[required=true]'); 

        if ($.trim($(field).val())){
            $(this).removeClass('err');
        } 
    });
});
```